# How to load CSV files data from S3 to MySQL RDS Using Lambda?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROY7q.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aitpA.png)
Let's say
Database name = EmployeeDB
In this Database we are having **5 tables** which are **table1, table2, table3, table4 and table5**
and we also having **5 CSV files** which are **sketching, profile, reading, health, error**

**Scenario:**
Whenever CSV file upload in S3 bucket then it should trigger and load that CSV data in to particular table. (Ex: when **sketching** is uploaded then it should go to **table1** table)

To achieve this I tried Lambda function and this is code I have used.

```
import json
import boto3
import csv
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# Read CSV file content from S3 bucket
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    # print(event)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    csv_file = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    csv_file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=csv_file)
    lines = csv_file_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()
    
    results = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines):
        results.append(row.values())
    print(results)
    
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com',database='employeedb',user='xxxxxx',password='xxxxxx')
    
    tables_dict = {
        'sketching': 'INSERT INTO table1 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
        'profile': 'INSERT INTO table2 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
        'reading': 'INSERT INTO table3 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
        'health': 'INSERT INTO table4 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
        'error': 'INSERT INTO table5 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
    }
    if csv_file in tables_dict:
        mysql_empsql_insert_query = tables_dict[csv_file]
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(mysql_empsql_insert_query,results)
        connection.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, f"Record inserted successfully from {csv_file} file")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

This code is not working for me and it triggered in cloudwatch but it is not loading data in to table1 or any table when I uploaded sketching.

Can anyone please help me with the code changes with my scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary with your files and queries. For every file/table a different insert query is needed.

```
tables_dict = {
  'sketching.csv': 'INSERT INTO table1.sketching (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',
  'profile.csv': '',
  'reading.csv': '',
  'health.csv': '',
  'error.csv': ''
}

if csv_file in tables_dict:
  mysql_empsql_insert_query = tables_dict[csv_file]
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.executemany(mysql_empsql_insert_query,results)
  connection.commit()
  print(cursor.rowcount, f"Record inserted successfully from {csv_file} file")
```

Comment: Hi @kgiannakakis ... i tried as you said and i uploaded sketching csv file in s3 and cloudwatch is triggered the values but data is not loading to table1 or any table. Data is not loading to RDS. Can you please look again ?

i uploaded the code what i used after your changes. Please check

Comment: If the file name is 'sketching.csv', then the dict should have a key 'sketching.csv' and not 'sketching'. Debug your code that you actually get into the `if csv_file in tables_dict`. Also, verify that your insert queries are correct.

Comment: Hey bro the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code you can use

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://db-bucket-name/folder-name/test.csv' INTO TABLE table-name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"+'"'+"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Import csv file data into PostgreSQL db table by using pandas in aws lambda...

```py
import psycopg2
import boto3
import pandas


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
db = psycopg2.connect(user="xyz",
                      database="xyz",
                      password="xyz",
                      port=xxxx,
                      host="xyz")

cursor = db.cursor()
bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

csv_file = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
csv_obj = s3_client.get_object(bucket=bucket_name, key=csv_file)
csv_data = pandas.read_csv(csv_obj)

sql = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (%s,%s,%s);"

for i, row in scv_data.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql,tuple(row))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).